# Google Chrome never shows me autocomplete search suggestions

Tags: google-chrome

What I want:

[image]

But when I'm logged into Chrome, I never see these suggestions. I only see suggestions are from my own history and bookmarks. How do I change this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How do I change this?

1. Open Chrome.
2. In the top right, click the Chrome menu [image: Chrome menu] .
3. Click "Settings" > "Show advanced settings".
4. In the "Privacy" section, check "Use a prediction service" to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar.

Answer (score 3):

If "Use a prediction service" is checked but you're still not getting search suggestions, then whichever search you have set to default may be one that does not support the "Use a prediction service" setting. All the search engines under "Default search settings" (Settings > Search > Manage search engines) support this setting, as do a few others you can add (or that are auto-added) under "Other search engines" (e.g. DuckDuckGo).

I've also noticed that when I manually add Google search and make it default, search suggestions do not show up, even if I use the exact same search string as the default Google search. So, if you've accidentally deleted your Google default search setting, you may need to reset your Chrome settings to default (Settings > Show advanced settings > Reset settings) to get the default search setting back. I was in this predicament, but I did not reset Chrome's settings -- rather, I noticed one day that the Google default search setting was back, and I only needed to make it default. So I assume this setting was re-added upon updating Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy. By ***RESET*** Chrome Setting:

1. open **Google chrome**.
2. click on **three vertical dots** (top right corner).
3. click **setting**.
4. click on **advanced** at last.
5. click on **RESET**.

After **RESET** Google Chrome will show autocomplete search suggestions.

Comment: Will this reset other settings as well? If so, you should include a bit of warning in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Show Autofill predictions can be enabled at chrome://flags/#show-autofill-type-predictions](http://chrome://flags/#show-autofill-type-predictions)